# Passing data from view to controller using ajax is not working

Tags: ajax, cakephp-2.3

I am using ajax to pass data from view to controller there is an error
in the view

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data:{"username": "test"}, 
    url:"/pubad/annonces/test/",
    success : function(data) {
      alert(data);// will alert "ok"

    },
    error : function() {
     //  alert("false");
    }
});
```

in my controller i have this function

```
public function test() { 
if( $this->request->is('ajax') ) {
    $this->autoRender = false;
}
if ($this->request->isPost()) {  
 $varibale1 = $this->params['data']['username'] ;
//$this->setJsVar('username',  $varibale1);
debug($varibale1);die();
}}
```

i have this error 
Undefined index:  username
please can any one help me

Answer (score 0):

Ajax will send the data over `$this->request->data` or in case you insist on the way you're doing it right now, you'd probably need to use `$this->params['named']['data']` as the only params already accessible are for controller, actions and other reserved ones, but for other custom ones you access them trough the `named` array in `$this->params`.